# Updating fields of a Couchbase document if it exists by Go

Tags: go, couchbase, gocb, go-couchbase

I am using `gocb` library. I want to update specific field of a document.

However if the document does not exist, I don't want to do anything I will just produce an error message.

You can say that first retrieve the full document itself and make update and then insert it.It is possible right. But I want to use a ready for use method for this purpose if there is any. Since I don't want to retrieve the document. I just want to update some fields of it.

Is there a way for this in `gocb` library?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update parts of the document, you can look at [sub-document operations](https://docs.couchbase.com/go-sdk/current/howtos/subdocument-operations.html). It only transmits the accessed sections of the document over the network making it more efficient for small changes.
Example: https://couchbase.live/examples/basic-go-subdoc-mutate

If you want to rewrite the entire document, you are looking for Replace() which replaces an existing document with a new one. It is similar to Upsert() except that it can only replace existing documents & not create new ones.

General Reference:https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/guides/updating-data.html